# How to import data set in R

Tags: r

I want to import wine data set from csv file in R on ubuntu machine.
How to import it and use it?
Here is the code I tried:

```
x<-read.csv(wine,header=TRUE)
```

Comment: read.csv("wine.csv", header = TRUE) might work a bit better. Avoid using variables named x.

Comment: What is the current result? What doesn't work? Please post the error message if any.

Answer (score 2):

you are correctly using read.csv. The first argument needs to be either a variable which contains your file name, or the file name as a string, eg

```
wine<-"wine.csv"
data<-read.csv(wine,header=TRUE)
```

or

```
data<-read.csv("wine.csv",header=TRUE)
```

If the file you want to read is located in your active directory, just use the file name as shown above, if it is located somewhere else, you either use

```
setwd(directory)
```

to change to the right directory, or you need to use the path to the file when calling read.csv().